# Function involving real values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a function satisfying $f(x/2+y/2)=(f(x)+f(y))/2$, for all real $x$ and $y$.
If $f'(0)$ exists and equal to $-1$ , then $f(2)$ equals: ?

I have tried this question by putting various values of $x$ and $y$ and I got $4$ equations and $4$ variables but still could not get the answer and I did not use $f'(0)$

Comment: Should it be $f((x+y)/2)=(f(x)+f(y))/2$?  The only reason I ask is the lack of symmetry in your version.  Also is it that $f'(0)=-1$?  It looks like there are primes on the $f$ but in the font I see they are not clear.  Are you given that $f$ is differentiable everywhere or at least continuous?

Comment: No i posted the exact questiin itself.

Comment: There is no information about continuous or differentiable

Comment: @dxix OP claims $f\left(x+\dfrac{y}{2}\right)$ is correct.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Point taken (though I am somewhat skeptical). In the meantime, I retracted my "duplicate" vote until this is cleared up.

Comment: @EshaSingla `There is no information about continuous or differentiable` But yes, you are given that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @dxix Also skeptical.

Comment: If you are solving a multiple choice question , you can guess some functions that satisfy your condition for example $f(x) = -x$ so $f(2) = -2$

Comment: @nonlinearthought If the OP really meant $f(x+\frac{y}{2})$ on the LHS then $f(x)=-x$ doesn't work. Otherwise if it's $f(\frac{x+y}{2})$ then $f(x)=-x+c$ works for any $c$ so there is no unique answer from the given conditions.

Comment: Hey Esha,   when you want write math notation in Latex you must put your expression in $$.  One way to learn latex, is to looking at the edit history of your question or answers that has been made by users. Compare your written formula with edited version.

Comment: I have editted the question. please answer it now.

Answer (score 2):

Put $y=0$. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$

$$f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(0)}{2}$$

$$f(x)=f(0)$$

$f$ is a constant function and $f'(x)=0\ne-1$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Such a function does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \ne b$.

Solve $x + y/2 = a; y+x/2 = b$ so $y = \frac {4b - 2a}3$ so $x = \frac {4a-2b}3; y = \frac {4b - 2a}3$.

So $f(a) = f (x + y/2) =\frac {f(x) + f(y)}2 = f(y + x/2) = f(b)$.

So the function is constant and $f'(x) = 0 \ne -1$.

So the problem has no solution.